# AVFoundation how to add animation while video recording

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, video-capture, video-processing

I am building an app which has video recording. I want to add some animations while user is recording video. I have tried lots of methods. But I couldn't find any solution. Which way sould I use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried, just as you, to build my own animations while recording videos. But my results weren't as good as I expected so I switched to use a **marvelous library** which is [SCRecorder](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder). There's an example project which will allow you to understand the library and make fantastic things with it.

If your animations are not too much complex, maybe this tutorial will be sufficient : [AVFoundation Tutorial: Adding Overlays and Animations to Videos](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos).

I know that link-only answers are not well appreciated, but the code will be very different according to what you want to do.

Comment: I have userd SCRecoder before. I didn't know that it has this capability. Iwill try it. I saw that tutorial too. I need to add animation while video recording at preview layer. Can i add CALayer while recoding video?

Comment: Yep. Using SCRecorder I have been able to : add a color filter, add text/image overlay (or whatever you can code in a UIView) over video (it's what you call CALayer but it's easier and better with SCRecorder method), merge several videos, etc.

Comment: So, can i add animation such as snowing or laughing emoji animate with SCRecorder? If the answer yes. it will be great:)

Comment: Well, the answer is **YES** ! :) Take a look at `SCWatermarkOverlayView.m`, in it you just have to build your view that will be applied over the video.

Comment: Thank you so much. Final question. Can i show that view at preview layer likes snapchat or msqrd app? Do i have to add the animations after video recoding. I want to add animations while recording.

Comment: It's possible, but the way I did is a kind of *hack*. In fact, what you have to do is to add the SCWatermarkOverlayView as a subview over your player. This way, you'll see the animation before recording, even if they are not incrusted on the video yet.